# Safe to use rice cooker after mold grew on rice?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker, mold

So I left brown rice in my rice cooker for 10+ days and unsurprisingly, some dark mold grew on the rice while I was gone. Will hot water and detergent be enough to remove all mold spores from the rice cooker, or should I just toss out the whole thing lest I die from mold spore toxicity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hot water and detergent might be enough, but after serious mold growth, I'd use a disinfectant. The easiest way to do this would be to disinfect your cooker with bleach, which is very effective at killing mold on non-porous surfaces. After thoroughly washing and rinsing your cooker, make a solution of 10 parts water to 1 part bleach and allow it to soak in your cooker for a few minutes, then dump it out and allow the cooker to air dry.

[Using Bleach on Mold](http://www.spore-tech.com/viewCategory.asp?idCategory=78) (note that the caveat here is that bleach isn't effective for porous surfaces. Anything that you're cooking on should be an acceptable surface for using bleach on.)

Comment: My rice cooker insert and lid are dishwasher safe. Barring that, I totally concur with bleach.